# Lift side Two Column Fix and Remaining Right Side Should have Scroll bar

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have created HTML helper grid having RowSpan in tbody which run for perticular Scenario

in MVC3 Application.Now I want to fix starting Two Columns and reamining coulmns will have

Scroll functionality on x-Axis.

Can anybody give me an idea about this.

Thanks in Advance.

I have tried below js code using DataTable.js plug-ins.

```
  function PopulateApprovalGrid() {
        var oTable = $('#grid').dataTable({
          "sScrollY": "300px",
         "bPaginate": false,
       "sScrollX": "100%",
       "sScrollXInner": "150%",
      "bScrollCollapse": true,
      "bSort":false 
   });

  new FixedColumns(oTable);
 }
```

Comment: Please post what you have already tried.

Comment: I have pasted code which I done.

Comment: Before posting a question here you had to take a look http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedColumns/two_columns.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have seen that link before but its not working for me as my Grid is having RowSpan in Table body.

Comment: I dont't see how RowSpan should affect to not work.

Comment: Could you please tell me how I can add screenshot here so I can share you shareshot here for more clear Idea.